# Can I add columns in a QListView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qlistview

Can I add columns in a QListView object??

here's something I found [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/23397/how-to-add-columns-items-to-a-qlistview.html):

```
model->setHeaderData( 0, Qt::Horizontal, "numéro" );
model->setHeaderData( 1, Qt::Horizontal, "prénom" );
model->setHeaderData( 2, Qt::Horizontal, "nom"    );
//...
model->setData( model->index( line, 0 ), contact->num(),    Qt::DisplayRole );
model->setData( model->index( line, 1 ), contact->prenom(), Qt::DisplayRole );
model->setData( model->index( line, 2 ), contact->nom(),    Qt::DisplayRole );
```

Since I'm using Qt Creator 2.0.1, I figured my model would be:

```
ui->ObjectName->model()
```

The Code snippet was added in the main window constructor's implementation after the:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
```

The application builds successfully but I get a: "The program has unexpectedly finished." at runtime.

Any Ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe QListView supports multiple columns.  You can use a QTreeWidget instead, it supports multiple columns.

Comment: Or, if you don't need nested elements, a `QTableView` or a `QTableWidget`.