# Creating a listbox-like control in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, listbox

I am a beginner at QT and I have been trying to port a GUI project over from raw Win32 to QT. Only problem is I cannot find the name for some controls in the QT framework such as the pictured one below.

[image]

I believe it is called a listbox in C# and C++ and I used some code to put the title bar up at the top containing "Update, Version, Size, Date". What would this translate to in QT? I have tried the tableview from QT but it only succeeds in making a Microsoft Excel type box with rows and columns, my goal is only to get vertical columns with a title at the top. Thank you!

Comment: How about [Qt Widget Gallery.](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/gallery.html) And if you just start Qt Creator or Qt Designer and play with the widgets and especially layouts for an hour or two, it will be a time well spent.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for that wonderful link. Helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QListBox` was [deprecated](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/porting4.html) in Qt 4, and was replaced by [`QListView`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html).

For the type of multi-column control pictured, [`QTreeWidget`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) should work.

Comment: I have looked into that too. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506817/can-i-add-columns-in-a-qlistview-in-qt you cannot add columns to the QListBox though which is my main question. Is that answer false?

Comment: QTableView/QTableWidget are probably what you're looking fore.

Comment: Sorry, I only answered the first part of your question. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `ListBox` control, **that's a `ListView` control**.

Not sure what Qt calls it, but since they prefix everything with a Q, I'd imagine it's **`QListView`**.

The `ListView` is like a super-duper `ListBox` that also has a column header attached to it when you set it to display in "Details" view.